# Why is it not possible to assign a variable in the class body?

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment

I'm new to C++ and I was wondering why, in the following code, can the variable `xyz` be assigned like this

```
class Fraction {
public:
    int num, denom;
    int xyz = 0;

    // Constructors
    Fraction() {
        num = 0;
        denom = 1;
    }

    Fraction(int n, int d) {
        num = n;
        denom = d;
    }
};
```

but if written like this

```
class Fraction {
public:
    int num, denom;
    int xyz;
    xyz = 0;

    // Constructors
    Fraction() {
        num = 0;
        denom = 1;
    }

    Fraction(int n, int d) {
        num = n;
        denom = d;
    }
};
```

returns errors on compilation, namely:

> error: C2059: syntax error: '='

and

> error: C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Comment: Do you want the rationale?

Comment: A method is a piece of code where statements can be executed. Outside of the method inside the class all you can have is declaration with/without initialization. `xyz=0` is a statement rather than an declaration/initialization and hence it is not allowed.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (which I almost certainly am), but it seems to me that 'int xyz = 0' both declares that xyz is an integer and sets its value to zero, whereas 'xyz = 0' only does the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xyz = 0` is an assignment expression. There are many contexts in which expressions can appear in C++, but when it comes to ordinary expressions that produce executable code they can only appear in *initializers* and in *statements*. And statements are basically the primary example of *executable code* in C++ language. In C++ language *executable code* (i.e. statements) is supposed to be written inside functions. That's just how the language works.

So, in your case the only way to somehow "plant" your expression outside of a function is to use it in an *initializer*. For example you can do something like this

```
struct S
{
    int a;
    int b = (a = 42);
};
```

But this trick is ugly, ill-advised and has no meaningful applications I know of.

Your first syntax is initialization syntax. The `=` symbol is not an assignment operator, but rather just a syntactic element of initializer syntax. Even in this case the actual initialization code will ultimately become a part of *constructor* code. So, even that code will end up being a part of a function.

Comment: So does the statement 'xyz=0' when used in a method after xyz has been declared do something different than writing 'int xyz = 0' when initializing? In both cases if I print the value xyz I get 0.

Comment: @James Machin: `int xyz = 0` in class definition produces implicit initialization code, which becomes part of the class's constructor. It is always executed at the very beginning of the constructor. If you use a "manual" assignment `xyz = 0;` in some member function, then it will only take place if/when you call that function and if/when execution reaches the `xyz = 0;` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing with initialization and assignment, they're different things at all. Yes, assignment statment is not allowed in the class member declaration, but for the 1st case it's [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization);

> Through a default member initializer, which is simply a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration

Answer (score 2):

> why, in the following code, can the variable xyz be assigned like this
>
> ```
> int xyz = 0;
> ```
>
> but if written like this
>
> ```
> int xyz;
> xyz = 0;
> ```
>
> returns errors on compilation

That's because `int xyz = 0` is not "assignment", it's "initialization". Initialization is allowed in class body, whereas assignment is not.

Answer (score 1):

Because class is just a blueprint, similar to a declaration. You can initialize using a constructor however.

Answer (score 0):

The first one

> int xyz = 0

is valid for C++11 standards.

But in the second case using **xyz = any value** in the class prototype is forbidden as the compiler expect to just know the data types of variables not its values. Also in general the class prototype should be a blueprint and not be used for variables assignment and manipulations.